# Probability that target will be hit once

Tags: probability, random-variables

Four groups can be formed from N shooters. a1 are excellent shooters a2 are good ones a3 are fair ones and a4 are poor. The probability that a shooter in group i hits the target is pi. Two shooters are chosen at random to shoot same target. Find the probability that target will be hit at least once.

Comment: Do we have $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=N$ here? And what are your own thoughts about it? Add this to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the first shooter chosen comes from group $i$ and the second comes from group $j$ then the probability of at least one hit is: $$1-(1-p_i)(1-p_j)$$

Denoting the probability that the first shooter chosen comes from group $i$ and the second comes from group $j$ by $p_{ij}$ we can express the probability of at least one hit by:$$\sum_{i=1}^4\sum_{j=1}^4p_{ij}[1-(1-p_i)(1-p_j)]$$

It remains to find expressions for $p_{ij}$ in $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ which I will leave up to you.

Also note that $p_{ij}=p_{ji}$